# Golang project Travis CI Build fails with error `Makefile:15: recipe for target 'test' failed`

Tags: go, makefile, travis-ci

I have set up travis build for my Github project [Captain](https://github.com/alwindoss/captain)
The contents of `.travis.yml` is:

```
language: go

go:
  - 1.12.x

script:
  make

env:
  - GO111MODULE=on GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org
```

The contents of my `Makefile` is:

```
# Go parameters
BINARY_FOLDER=./bin
GOCMD=go
GOBUILD=$(GOCMD) build
GOCLEAN=$(GOCMD) clean
GOTEST=$(GOCMD) test
GOGET=$(GOCMD) get
BINARY_NAME=captain
BINARY_UNIX=$(BINARY_NAME)_unix

all: test build
build: 
        $(GOBUILD) -o $(BINARY_FOLDER)/$(BINARY_NAME) ./cmd/...
test: 
        $(GOTEST) -v ./...
clean: 
        rm -rf $(BINARY_FOLDER)
run: all
        $(BINARY_FOLDER)/$(BINARY_NAME)


# Cross compilation
build-linux:
        CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 $(GOBUILD) -o $(BINARY_UNIX) -v
docker-build:
        docker run --rm -it -v "$(GOPATH)":/go -w /go/src/bitbucket.org/rsohlich/makepost golang:latest go build -o "$(BINARY_UNIX)" -v
```

When ever the travis build triggers it errors out saying:

```
go test -v ./...
go: finding github.com/gorilla/mux v1.7.3
go: finding github.com/lib/pq v1.2.0
go: finding github.com/google/uuid v1.1.1
go: finding github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock v1.3.3
go: downloading github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock v1.3.3
go: downloading github.com/lib/pq v1.2.0
go: extracting github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock v1.3.3
go: extracting github.com/lib/pq v1.2.0
# github.com/alwindoss/captain/cmd/captain
cmd/captain/main.go:4:2: undefined: Run
=== RUN   TestCreateWorklistPositiveScenario
2019/08/10 14:56:19 Creating Worklist
2019/08/10 14:56:19 {"id": "ID", "name": "name"}
2019/08/10 14:56:19 Creating worklist in the RDBMS Store
2019/08/10 14:56:19 Last Inserted ID: 1
2019/08/10 14:56:19 ID = 1, affected = 1
--- PASS: TestCreateWorklistPositiveScenario (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestCreateWorklistWhenBadRequestIsSent
2019/08/10 14:56:19 Creating Worklist
2019/08/10 14:56:19 This is a bad request
--- PASS: TestCreateWorklistWhenBadRequestIsSent (0.00s)
PASS
ok      github.com/alwindoss/captain/internal/handler   0.005s
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

In the job log I see that all my tests pass but the build does not go beyond this. The very same `Makefile` works without issues locally on my Mac.

I am not sure where the issue is. In the Makefile or in the way I have configured the Travis CI.

Comment: `cmd/captain/main.go:4:2: undefined: Run` is the actual error

Comment: @Flimzy that was the error, it was passing on my laptop because I had that file in my system, it was the folder where that file existed was ignored in `.gitignore` therefore it was not pushed to the Github repository. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interesting error message is:

```
cmd/captain/main.go:4:2: undefined: Run
```

So on line 4 of your `main.go`, you refer to an undefined symbol `Run`.

Comment: that was the error, it was passing on my laptop because I had that file in my system, it was the folder where that file existed was ignored in .gitignore therefore it was not pushed to the Github repository. Thanks for the help!